# what kinds of projects (driver develompent /software )can we do with beagelbone back ?any suggesstion

Tags: project, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack

I am interested  to pursue project on Linux kernel development with beagle-bone back for my academic purpose.all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a 32 channels servos controller, using a PRU to generate pulses and speeds:

https://github.com/fma38/BeagleBone/tree/master/servos

(I just received my cape: it works fine!).

The values from linux host to PRU are given directly through data memory; it is enough for my needs, but it could be interesting to have a real kernel driver to control the servos.

I don't have the skills to help you doing this, though.